# I have this error when trying to run TensorBoard: ImportError: cannot import name 'parameter_server_strategy_v2' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I want to use tensorboard but get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'parameter_server_strategy_v2' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute' (C:\Users\Connor Lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\__init__.py)
```

I am using keras callbacks. Here is the code:

```
model = [...]
logdir = os.path.join(os.curdir, "my_dir")
t_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir,histogram_freq=1)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=50, callbacks=[t_callback], validation_data=val_data)
```

I'm on windows 10, running TensorFlow-gpu with Anaconda,
Python 3.7,
tensorflow (-gpu) version is 2.3.0,
tensorboard version 2.30

Any Idea on how to fix it?

I have tried on both Pycharm and Jupiter, same error

Full Error

```
(gputest) C:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Learning>tensorboard --logdir=my_dir
2021-02-09 16:52:16.003796: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\Scripts\tensorboard-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import beholder_plugin_loader
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder.beholder import Beholder
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\beholder.py", line 225, in <module>
    class BeholderHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import run_config
  File "C:\Users\Connor Lab\anaconda3\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\run_config.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import parameter_server_strategy_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'parameter_server_strategy_v2' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute' (C:\Users\Connor Lab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65052400/i-have-this-error-when-trying-to-import-tensorflow-hub-cannot-import-name-para) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your answer